# Memset an object

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class A
   {
     private:
  int a;
  int b;
  public:
  A():a(10),b(20){};
  A(int ad,int bd):a(ad),b(bd){};
  void printvalues()
  {
        cout<<a << " " <<b<<endl;
  }
};

int main()
{

  A a(5,12);

  memset(&a,sizeof(A),0);
  a.printvalues();

  return 0;
}
```

memsetting the object to 0, do not seem to have any effect on the object. Can anyone help me understand this behavior.
output:
5 12

Comment: It should be noted that doing memset on a C++ object has some risks.  Never do it on a virtual object, in particular.

Comment: To be exact, it's undefined to use `memset` on non-POD types.

Comment: You should absolutely use the constructor for initializing the value. Setting the whole memory area of an object to 0 by a raw memory operation is asking for trouble.

Comment: That is dumb. Imagine manually writing a lot of `= nullptr` just to avoid quick memset in constructor

Answer (score 9):

You have the arguments to `memset` the wrong way round.  It's `memset(addr, value, number)`.

---

*Note: In C++, `memset` is usually avoided.*

Answer (score 5):

You got the memset wrong:

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

it should be:

```
memset(&a,0,sizeof(A));
```

In your example, you're setting `0` bytes of `a` to `sizeof(A)`, so, obviously, no change.

Comment: my bad, got it wrong. thanks for pointing out. Can we use this kind of operation, to initialize an object to 0 ?

Comment: @vamsi I don't know what "initialize an object to 0 means". If you want to reset members, use a method, not memset.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax of `memset` is `memset(&a,0,sizeof(A))` because the first parameter is the array or the variable, the second is the value and the third parameter is the number of bytes.

For more details about `memset` visit http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/.

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced the arguments to memset. At first I thought this is stunning!
Write this:`memset(&a,0,sizeof(A));`

And all will be as expected.